# Want to associate a controller to main page in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am currently creating an app that has a nav bar. I want a particular function to be invoked every time the submit button in the nav bar is pressed regardless of route/view. I am having trouble because here in my routes file I have created associations that changed based on route. The form is found in  `<form class="pure-form" ng-submit="somefunc()">`

**routes.js**

```
angular.module('LiveAPP', ['ngRoute',
                          'LiveAPP.main',
                          'LiveAPP.signUp',
                          'LiveAPP.artist'])

.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : '/home.html',
    controller  : 'mainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/signup',{
    templateUrl : '/signup.html',
    controller  : 'signUpCtrl'
  })
  .when('/artist',{
    templateUrl : '/artistpage.html',
    controller  : 'artistCtrl'
  })
})
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app='LiveAPP'>
  <div class="header">

    <form class="pure-form" ng-submit="somefunc(field)">

      <input ng-model="field" type="text" placeholder="Artist" name="field">
      <button type="submit">Search</button>

    </form>

    <a href="/#/signup">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="/#/artist">artistPage</a>

  </div>

  <div ng-view></div>

</body>
```

**mainCtrl**

```
angular.module('LiveAPP.main',[])
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$location',mainCtrl]);

function mainCtrl($scope,$http,$location){
  $scope.somefunc = function(searchvalue){
    console.log(searchvalue)
  }

};
```

Right now the submit button is associated with the mainCtrl which is related to the home.html. Any ideas?

Comment: `someFunc` is not defined in the scope of the form, so it shouldn't be invoked. Do you intend for it to be invoked?

Comment: Right so my question is how do I define it in the scope of the form which is in my index.html and isn't a view with an associated controller.

Comment: Just like you would do normally without `ngRoute` - add `ng-controller` at whatever scope you need with the controller where this function is defined

Comment: Gah. That's right. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 0):

In general you have a couple approaches:

1. If you need some logic to be available in more than one controller you can create a service and inject it to your controllers.
2. You can implement controller inheritance.

There are a couple ways to implement controller inheritance. 
This is one example of how to do that:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
    this.methodclick=function(){
      alert('I am Parents')
    }
   });
   app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($controller) {
   var ChildCtrl=this;
   ChildCtrl.child = $controller('MainCtrl',{});
   });
```

But in my opinion it is better to implement a service.